# How can I process the results of find in a bash script?

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to use an array to store a list of file names using the `find` command.

For some reason the array fails to work in the bash used by the school, my program works on my own laptop though.

So I was wondering if there's another way to do it, this is what i have:

```
array = (`find . -name "*.txt"`)  #this will store all the .txt files into the array
```

Then I can access the array items and make a copies of all the files using the cat command.

Is there another way to do it without using an array?

Comment: If you are only interested in files then you should limit find's results with `-type f`. It is valid to have a directory with .txt ending eg. dir.txt

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```sh
find . -name '*.txt' | while read line; do
    echo "Processing file '$line'"
done
```

For example, to make a copy:

```sh
find . -name '*.txt' | while read line; do
    echo "Copying '$line' to /tmp"
    cp -- "$line" /tmp
done
```

Comment: Using a `for` loop is definitely a better choice here. Using an array would work except that it reads the entire list into a variable and then iterates over the variable. This version reads each file name as it comes from `find` and processes it inline.

Comment: D.Shawley, could you please post a sample with a for loop? It should work for files with spaces in the name as well, I think.

Comment: Using **find** together with 'for' or 'while' is mostly a bad idea. You pass filenames as strings and get all the problems with whitespace and masking, while it is no problem to use the unmasked {} together with finds -exec, -execdir, -ok, -okdir. Try `a b.txt`.

Comment: I would be very careful with with construct if you want to loop to have side-effects. For example `a=1; seq 3 | while read line; do a=2; done; echo $a` prints `1`

Comment: Be careful: this `while` runs in a subshell because it's the second command in the pipeline, so changes made in that loop are not available after the loop exits. I had trouble getting this to append to a variable declared outside the loop. From here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691436/unable-to-add-element-to-array-in-bash

Comment: This can swallow part of filenames if something within the loop tries to read from stdin. Can lead to dangerous problems.

Answer (score 27):

I was having issue with Johannes Weiß's solution, if I was just doing an echo it would work for the full list of files. However, if I tried running ffmpeg on the next line the script would only process the first file it encountered. I assumed some IFS funny business due to the pipe but I couldn't figure it out and ran with a for loop instead:

```
for i in $(find . -name '*.mov' ); 
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: This fails for whitespace in file names

Answer (score 17):

I think starpause has the cleanest solution, however it fails when there is whitespaces in paths. This is fixed by setting `IFS`. The correct answer is therefore:

```bash
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(find . -name '*.mov' ); 
do
    echo "$i"
done
unset IFS
```

You unset IFS in order to reset behaviour for IFS and as to why the `$` is needed in `IFS=$'\n'`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting

Answer (score 11):

Just don't put blanks around the equals sign:

```
ar=($(find . -name "*.txt"))
```

Avoid backticks, if possible, since they're deprecated. They can be easily confused with apostroph, especially in poor fonts, and they don't nest so well.

In most cases you will be best served if you iterate through a find-result directly with -exec, -execdir, -ok or -okdir.

For and while loops are hard to do right when it comes to blanks in filenames or newlines and tabs.

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" -exec grep {} ";"
```

The {} doesn't need masking. 
You will often see a combination find/xargs which starts an additional process too:

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" | xargs grep {} ";"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -name '*.txt' | while IFS= read -r FILE; do
    echo "Copying $FILE.."
    cp "$FILE" /destination
done
```

Answer (score 0):

One more variant to change some variable inside while loop which uses subshell

```
concat=""

while read someVariable
do
    echo "someVariable: '$someVariable'"
    concat="$concat someVariable")
done < <(find "/Users/alex" -name "*.txt")

echo "concat: '$concat'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Generalized version tested with whitespace

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.46(2)-release
```

Make some horrible looking directories and files

```
mkdir "spaces test"
cd spaces\ test/
touch 'test one'{1..5}
touch 'testone'{1..5}
mkdir test\ two
cd test\ two/
touch 'test one'{1..5}
```

Create and run the script

```
set -u
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done < <(find "spaces test" -type f)
```