# Using an alias in find -exec

Tags: bash, find, alias

I have a very long command in bash, which I do not want to type all the time, so I put an alias in my .profile

```
alias foo='...'
```

Now I want to execute this alias using find -exec

```
find . -exec foo '{}' \;
```

but find cannot find foo:

> find: foo: No such file or directory

Is it possible to use an alias in find?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, find doesn't know anything about your aliases. Aliases are not like environment variables in that they aren't "inherited" by child processes.

You can create a shell script with the same commands, set +x permissions and have it in your path. This will work with find.

Answer (score 19):

`find` itself doesn't know anything about aliases, but your shell does.  If you are using a recent enough version of `bash` (I think 4.0 added this feature), you can use `find . -exec ${BASH_ALIASES[foo]} {} \;` to insert the literal content of the alias at that point in the command line.

Answer (score 7):

Another way of calling an alias when processing the results of find is to use something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087001/how-can-i-process-the-results-of-find-in-a-bash-script#answer-2087038)

so the following should work:

```
alias ll="ls -al"
find . -type d | while read folder; do ll $folder; done
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using the `ll` commonly know alias for this example but you may use your alias instead, just replace `ll` in the following line with your alias (`foo`) and it should work:

```
find . -exec `alias ll | cut -d"'" -f2` {} \;
```

your case:

```
find . -exec `alias foo | cut -d"'" -f2` {} \;
```

Note it assumes your alias is quoted using the following syntax:

```
alias foo='your-very-long-command'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (or difficult / error-prone) to use aliases in the `find` command.
An easier way to achieve the desired result is putting the contents of the alias in a shellscript and run that shellscript:

```
alias foo | sed "s/alias foo='//;s/'$/ \"\$@\"/" > /tmp/foo
find -exec bash /tmp/foo {} \;
```

The sed command removes the leading `alias foo='` and replaces the trailing `'` by `"$@"` which will contain the arguments passed to the script.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing and pretty much implemented skjaidev's solution.

I created a bash script called findVim.sh with the following contents:

```
[ roach@sepsis:~ ]$ cat findVim.sh                                                                                                        #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
find . -iname $1 -exec vim '{}' \;
```

Then I added the the .bashrc alias as:

```
[ roach@sepsis:~ ]$ cat ~/.bashrc | grep fvim                                                                                         
alias fvim='sh ~/findVim.sh'
```

Finally, I reloaded .bashrc with source ~/.bashrc.

Anyways long story short I can edit arbitrary script files slightly faster with:
$ fvim foo.groovy

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable instead.

So instead of:

```
alias foo="echo test"
```

use:

```
foo="echo test"
```

then execute it either by command substitution or `eval`, for instance:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "eval $foo" \;
```

or:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "echo `$foo`" \;
```

Here is real example which is finding all non-binary files:

```
IS_BINARY='import sys; sys.exit(not b"\x00" in open(sys.argv[1], "rb").read())'
find . -type f -exec bash -c "python -c '$IS_BINARY' {} || echo {}" \;
```