# Have find use my command's alias instead of original

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

As a precaution, I have in my `.bashrc` file the following alias:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

so it would ask me to confirm anytime I delete a file.

I often use find to remove files as well, generally with the following form:

```
find ./*dat -mmin +10 -exec rm "{}" \;
```

In this case, the `rm` command use is the original one as it does not ask my permission before deleting files. Most of the times I do not mind, but I would still like to know why it behaves like that and if it's possible to have find use my alias version of the command. For the `rm` case, I could just add the `-i` option, but this is what alias are for in the first place.

Comment: Interesting question! The [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7689221/1983854) in the duplicate covers this: `find . -exec ${BASH_ALIASES[rm]} {} \;`

Comment: Yes that works just fine! I don't know how I missed that question. Thanks