# Bash Script - How nest loop to enter directories make symbolic link exit from that directorio and go to the next and do the same?

Tags: bash, path

i am GNU/Linux user, and well i use a lot "Wine" & "PlayOnLinux" but ever i prefer make symbolic link to move "Paths" of "Windows" for make me more ease to make backups of the data of programs.

i had write the follow script (had spanish variables names, because i am from venezuela and spanish is my native lang) :

The script content :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo '
Autor ----------------> Inukaze ( Venezuela )
Sitio ----------------> Removed for can publish the question
Correo-E -------------> bloginukaze@gmail.com
Licencia -------------> GPL 2

******* Inicio : Acerca de este guión ******** 

    Es un simple guion para cambiar la
    Ubicacion de los directorios 
    predeterminados

******** Fin : Acerca de este guión **********'

Prefijo="$HOME/.wine"
Objetivo="drive_c/users/inukaze"
BaseDeEnlace="/media/Compartido/Videojuegos/Partidas/Wine/inukaze"

#Crear Carpetas para la BaseDeEnlace en caso de que no exista:
if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/AppData"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/AppData" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Application Data"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Application Data" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Cookies"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Cookies" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Descargas"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Descargas" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Escritorio"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Escritorio" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Imagenes"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Imagenes" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Local Settings"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Local Settings" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Musica"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Musica" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Partidas"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Partidas" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Plantillas"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Plantillas" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Temp"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Temp" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Videos"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Videos" &> /dev/null
fi

#Borrar carpeta anterior :
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/AppData"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Application Data"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Cookies"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Descargas"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Documentos"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Escritorio"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Desktop"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Imagenes"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Local Settings"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Musica"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Saved Games"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Templates"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Temp"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Videos"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mi música"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis Documentos"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/My Documents"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis imágenes"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis vídeos"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Downloads"

# Crear Enlaces : 
for Directorio in $(find "$Prefijo" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d) ; do 
cd "$Directorio" && echo "Ingresando en $Directorio" || { echo "Error: No puedo entrar en $Directorio"; continue; }
    for Enlace in $(ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/AppData" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/AppData" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Application Data" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Application Data" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Cookies" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Cookies" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Descargas" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Descargas" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Documentos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Escritorio"  "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Escritorio" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Imagenes" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Imagenes" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Local Settings" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Local Settings" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Musica" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Musica" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Partidas" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Saved Games" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Plantillas" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Templates" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Temp" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Temp" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Videos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Videos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Musica" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mi música" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis Documentos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Imagenes" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis imágenes" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Videos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis vídeos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Descargas" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Downloads" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Descargas" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Descargas" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Escritorio" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Desktop" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/My Documents")
    do
        echo ${Enlace}
    done
done

# Prefijo de "PlayOnLinux"
Prefijo="$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/"
Objetivo="drive_c/users/inukaze/"
BaseDeEnlace="/media/Compartido/Videojuegos/Partidas/Wine/inukaze"

#Borrar carpeta anterior :
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/AppData"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Application Data"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Cookies"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Descargas"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Documentos"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Escritorio"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Imagenes"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Local Settings"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Musica"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Saved Games"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Templates"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Temp"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Videos"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mi música"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis Documentos"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis imágenes"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis vídeos"
rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Downloads"

# Crear Enlaces : 
for Directorio in $(find "$Prefijo" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d) ; do 
cd "$Directorio" && echo "Ingresando en $Directorio" || { echo "Error: No puedo entrar en $Directorio"; continue; }
    for Enlace in $(ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/AppData" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/AppData" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Application Data" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Application Data" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Cookies" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Cookies" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Descargas" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Descargas" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Documentos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Escritorio"  "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Escritorio" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Imagenes" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Imagenes" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Local Settings" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Local Settings" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Musica" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Musica" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Partidas" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Saved Games" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Plantillas" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Templates" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Temp" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Temp" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Videos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Videos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Musica" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mi música" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis Documentos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Imagenes" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis imágenes" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Videos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis vídeos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Descargas" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Downloads" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Descargas" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Descargas" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Escritorio" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Desktop" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/My Documents")
    do
        echo ${Enlace}
    done
done
```

The thing is i got errors with the second prefix, the PlayOnLinux folder prefix like :

```
ln: failed to created symbolic link to '/home/inukaze/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix//drive_c/users/inukaze//My Documents' : Does not exist the file or directory
```

What thing i need to take full path? becuase i notice 'wineprefix/**"empty instead name of existing folder"**/drive_c'

Well thanks for any help you can give me

Comment: You cannot reliably iterate `find` results this way because of word splitting names with space and special characters. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087038/7939871

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I process the results of find in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087001/how-can-i-process-the-results-of-find-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

I has solved the script right now is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo '
Autor ----------------> Inukaze ( Venezuela )
Sitio ----------------> Removed for can publish the question
Correo-E -------------> bloginukaze@gmail.com
Licencia -------------> GPL 2

******* Inicio : Acerca de este guión ******** 

    Es un simple guion para cambiar la
    Ubicacion de los directorios 
    predeterminados

******** Fin : Acerca de este guión **********'

Objetivo="drive_c/users/inukaze"
BaseDeEnlace="/media/Compartido/Videojuegos/Partidas/Wine/inukaze"

#Crear Carpetas para la BaseDeEnlace en caso de que no exista:
if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/AppData"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/AppData" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Application Data"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Application Data" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Cookies"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Cookies" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Descargas"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Descargas" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Escritorio"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Escritorio" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Imagenes"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Imagenes" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Local Settings"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Local Settings" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Musica"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Musica" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Partidas"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Partidas" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Plantillas"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Plantillas" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Temp"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Temp" &> /dev/null
fi

if test ! -d "$BaseDeEnlace/Videos"
then
    mkdir -p "$BaseDeEnlace/Videos" &> /dev/null
fi

# Borrar Carpeta Anterior & Crear Enlace : 
Prefijo="$HOME/.wine" ; cd "$Prefijo"
cd "$Prefijo/$Objetivo" && echo "Ingresando en $Prefijo"
    for Enlace in $(rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/AppData" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Application Data" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Cookies" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Descargas" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Documentos" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Escritorio" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Desktop" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Imagenes" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Local Settings" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Musica" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Saved Games" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Templates" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Temp" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Videos" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mi música" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis Documentos" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/My Documents" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis imágenes" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis vídeos" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Downloads" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/AppData" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/AppData" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Application Data" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Application Data" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Cookies" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Cookies" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Documentos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Escritorio"  "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Escritorio" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Imagenes" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Imagenes" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Local Settings" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Local Settings" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Musica" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Musica" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Partidas" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Saved Games" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Plantillas" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Templates" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Temp" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Temp" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Videos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Videos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Musica" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mi música" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis Documentos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Imagenes" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis imágenes" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Videos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Mis vídeos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Descargas" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Downloads" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Escritorio" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/Desktop" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos" "$Prefijo/$Objetivo/My Documents")
    do
        echo ${Enlace}
    done
    
# Prefijo de "PlayOnLinux"
Prefijo="$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix"
cd "$Prefijo"
Objetivo="drive_c/users/inukaze"
BaseDeEnlace="/media/Compartido/Videojuegos/Partidas/Wine/inukaze"

# Borrar Carpeta Anterior & Crear Enlace : 
for Directorio in $(ls -l | awk '{print$09}' | sed 's/\/*$//') ; do 
cd "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo" && echo "Ingresando en $Prefijo/$Directorio" || { echo "Error: No puedo entrar en $Directorio"; continue; }
    for Enlace in $(rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/AppData" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Application Data" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Cookies" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Descargas" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Documentos" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Escritorio" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Desktop" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Imagenes" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Local Settings" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Musica" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Saved Games" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Templates" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Temp" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Videos" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Mi música" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Mis Documentos" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/My Documents" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Mis imágenes" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Mis vídeos" ; rm -rf "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Downloads" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/AppData" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/AppData" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Application Data" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Application Data" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Cookies" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Cookies" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Documentos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Escritorio"  "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Escritorio" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Imagenes" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Imagenes" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Local Settings" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Local Settings" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Musica" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Musica" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Partidas" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Saved Games" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Plantillas" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Templates" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Temp" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Temp" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Videos" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Videos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Musica" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Mi música" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Mis Documentos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Imagenes" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Mis imágenes" ;  ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Videos" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Mis vídeos" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Descargas" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Downloads" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Descargas" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Descargas" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Escritorio" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/Desktop" ; ln -sf "$BaseDeEnlace/Documentos" "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/My Documents")
    do
        echo ${Enlace}
    done
done
```

Comment: Now you replace bad practice of iterating find result by the bad awful practice of parsing the result of ls and iterating it `for Directorio in $(ls -l | awk '{print$09}' | sed 's/\/*$//') ; do `

Answer (score 0):

Fixed and simplified code:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo 'Autor ----------------> Inukaze ( Venezuela )
Sitio ----------------> Removed for can publish the question
Correo-E -------------> bloginukaze@gmail.com
Licencia -------------> GPL 2

******* Inicio : Acerca de este guión ******** 

    Es un simple guion para cambiar la
    Ubicacion de los directorios 
    predeterminados

******** Fin : Acerca de este guión **********'

Objetivo='drive_c/users/inukaze'
BaseDeEnlace='/media/Compartido/Videojuegos/Partidas/Wine/inukaze'

directories=('AppData' 'Application Data' 'Cookies' 'Descargas'
  'Documentos' 'Escritorio' 'Imagenes' 'Local Settings'
  'Musica' 'Partidas' 'Plantillas' 'Temp' 'Videos')

#Crear Carpetas para la BaseDeEnlace en caso de que no exista:
for dir in "${directories[@]}"; do
  dirpath="$BaseDeEnlace/$dir"
  ! [ -d "$dirpath" ] && mkdir -p -- "$dirpath"
done

# Borrar Carpeta Anterior & Crear Enlace :
Prefijo="$HOME/.wine"
cd "$Prefijo" || exit 1
cd "$Prefijo/$Objetivo" && echo "Ingresando en $Prefijo"

for Enlace in "${directories[@]}"; do
  link_dest="$Prefijo/$Objetivo/$Enlace"
  link_src="$BaseDeEnlace/$Enlace"
  rm -rf -- "$link_dest"
  ln -sf -- "$link_src" "$link_dest"
  echo "${Enlace}"
done

# Prefijo de "PlayOnLinux"
Prefijo="$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix"
cd "$Prefijo" || exit 1
Objetivo='drive_c/users/inukaze'
BaseDeEnlace='/media/Compartido/Videojuegos/Partidas/Wine/inukaze'

# Borrar Carpeta Anterior & Crear Enlace :
for Directorio in */; do
  if cd "$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo"; then
    printf 'Ingresando en %s\n' "$Prefijo/$Directorio"
  else
    printf 'Error: No puedo entrar en %s\n' "$Directorio" >&2
    continue
  fi
  for Enlace in "${directories[@]}"; do
    link_dest="$Prefijo/$Directorio/$Objetivo/$Enlace"
    link_src="$BaseDeEnlace/$Enlace"
    rm -rf -- "$link_dest"
    ln -sf -- "$link_src" "$link_dest"
    echo "${Enlace}"
  done
done
```